# get_node crashing game when node is deleted

Tags: godot

First of all, I'm new to programming in general so I'm kind of assuming there's a simple answer to this question, I just couldn't seem to find it anywhere.
I'm making a simple platformer game with enemies that move toward the player. I used this code in the enemy's script underneath the physics process to get the player position:

```
player_position = get_parent().get_node("Player").get_position
```

However, upon the player being queue_freed when health reaches 0, the game crashes immediately and I get a null error due to there being no Player node. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

You could just set `$Player.visibility` to false instead of freeing, or you could check if the player exists first using `get_parent().has_node("Player")`

Answer (score 1):

When you destroy the player, the physics process function is still trying to get the player node, even though it doesn't exist. So, as Lucas said, you could replace:

```py
player_position = get_parent().get_node("Player").get_position
```

with something like...

```py
if get_parent().has_node("Player"):
    player_position = get_parent().get_node("Player").get_position
```

(Before setting `player_position`, it will check if the player node even exists)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use weakref (documentation [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_weakref.html?#description)).

If you declare a weak reference:

```
var player_ref: WeakRef = null
```

and store that reference:

```
func store_player_node():
    var player_ref = weakref(get_parent().get_node("Player"))
```

Then you can access that reference later:

```
if player_ref.get_ref():
    player_position = player_ref.get_ref().get_position
```

Weakref has advantage over using `get_parent().get_node("Player")`. Let's imagine the following scenario:

1. `Player` dies and its node is removed from the parent node's children.
2. New node is created with name `Player` and added to the scene tree at the same place as the dead `Player`.
3. `get_parent().get_node("Player")` will return a node and the code will not crash. However, it will be a new `Player` node, not the old one, and I think this is usually undesired.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using `WeakRef` didn't work for me.

I had to use `is_instance_valid()`

Like so:

```
if is_instance_valid(player) and player.position.x < position.x:
```

This worked beautifully.